# jquerymobile allow image to resize within its actual dimensions only

Tags: image, jquery-mobile, image-resizing

I am using jquery mobile and I want to stop images from being resized larger than their actual dimensions, but still allow resizing if smaller particularly when displaying on desktop

I have rolled my own code below which works ok(ish) but I currently have 2 issues

1. when the image is resized beyond its actual size I get screen flicker as the image is displayed but the code kicks in and redisplays it to a smaller size
2. it doesn't always resize when double clicking the browser title bar

Can anyone help/advise on this please?

```html
<img  id="imgs" style="width:90%;" src="images/mypic.jpg" />
```

```js
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function (event) {
    resizeimage(awidth, aheight)
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeimage(awidth, aheight)
});

function resizeimage(maxwidth, maxheight) {

    var width = $(imgs).width(); // Current image width
    var height = $(imgs).height(); // Current image height

    // **** this is trace output only
    //$(windowwidth).text($(window).width());
    //$(windowheight).text($(window).height());
    //$(iwidth).text($(imgs).width());
    //$(iheight).text($(imgs).height());

    if (parseInt(width, 10) > maxwidth) {
        //$(info).text('bigger');  // trace output
        $(imgs).css("width", maxwidth); // dont allow image to resize larger than its actual                              size
    } else {
        //$(info).text('smaller');          // trace output
        $(imgs).css("width", "100%"); // allow image to resize below its actual size 
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to resize image according to screen width/height or parent div width/height?

Comment: In this instance it is screen / window width

Comment: http://jsbin.com/daxuga/1/edit?html,js fixed an error in previous demo

Comment: was wondering what was wrong :-) 
the screen flash and the resize on header click is now good but the image still resizes beyond its natural size

Comment: The code resize image based on window's width. the flashing is caused by resize although I've used `throttledresize` event instead of `resize`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Not sure I'm being clear about what I'm trying to achieve
I'm happy for image to be resized as long as when it is resized it stays smaller than actual image size. BUT stop image resize if window resize makes image larger than actual image size.

Comment: If you know the original image size, just set the CSS max-width and max-height values. e.g. if original width is 600px and original height is 300px, then <img style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 300px" src="" />:  http://jsbin.com/denivuwilo/2/edit

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it didnt work.... now it does, I must have made a typo or something!.. Anyway it works now, thanks for your help.